# Override previously used functions

Tags: php, irc, auto-update, keep-alive

I'm in the process of making an irc bot with PHP. While developing, I want to be able to dynamically load and unload classes/functions.

Mind you, the PHP is keep-alive.

ex:

**Main File**:

```
class stuff {

    function stuff() { echo 'this'; }

    function replaceFunction() {
        remove(stuff);
        add(stuff);
    }
}
$stuff = new stuff();
```

## Next

**I edit a function**:

```
function stuff() { echo 'that'; }
```

So ideally, now that it's edited, all I have to do is trigger replaceFunction() to update the old function.

How can I make this actually work?

Comment: Redefining the class of objects in memory? I wonder how that would look like... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you need is to have a class that has a function and you want to be able to exchange the functionality of *that* function by triggering the `replaceFunction`, you can assign some closure to that class or similar:

```
class stuff {
    private $callback;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->callback = array($this, 'stuff');
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        call_user_func($this->callback);
    }   

    private function stuff() { echo 'This'; }

    function replace($function) {
        $this->callback = $function;
    }
}


$stuff = new stuff;

$stuff(); # original function

$stuff->replace(function() { echo 'That'; });

$stuff(); # replaced function
```

Or the short version:

```
$stuff = function() {echo 'This';};

$stuff(); # original function

$stuff = function() {echo 'That';};

$stuff(); # replaced function
```

The class has the benefit that you have more control about assigning and invoking the function.

Comment: About what kind of security do you think? This is basically injecting code, so I assume you know what you do, don't you?

Comment: I saw (and had to fix) a security hole (disaster) once that resulted from a function name being passed as a variable. So security is now the first thing I think about when I see people accepting function names as variables. But that was a url variable, whereas here any security problem would be developer created. Your answer seems good.

Comment: @Ted: Yes, that would be a developer created issue. And go for the class variant (first example). That done you can later on stay in control whenever a function is called or changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can remove the functions first

```
runkit_function_remove ( string $funcname );
```

Use `function_exists()` to check if the function already exists.

EDIT:

```
class stuff {
    function replaceFunction() {
        runkit_function_remove('stuff');
        function stuff() { echo 'New stuff'; }
    }
}
$stuff = new stuff();
$stuff->replaceFunction();
```

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear, this is definitely a good start.